# How to write an array of geometrical coordinates of the cubic mesh of the cube?

Tags: arrays, matlab, 3d

I have seen the following link to create cube with 3D mesh.
[How to plot 3D grid (cube) in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309188/how-to-plot-3d-grid-cube-in-matlab)
This is very useful. Can anybody answer how to export the geometrical coordinates of each mesh element in the for of array. Array should consist of A=A1;A2:A3.. where A1=x1,y1,z1 A2=x2,y2,z2....

Thanks

Comment: you mean something like [meshgrid](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html?refresh=true)?

Answer (score 0):

`[X, Y, Z]=meshgrid(sx:ex, sy:ey, sz:ez);` will created three matrices the same size as your grid with x, y, z coordinates of each point.

To get these into a single matrix you can first reshape them into a column vector using `x=reshape(X, numel(X), 1);` and similar for y and z. Unless you do something odd the ordering should be consistent between the three.

The just stitch the three columns together if you need to. `A=[x, y, z];`