# 3D grid with spheres in each cell

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am attempting to create a diagram similar to this.

[image]

A diagram of a 3D grid with spheres in each cell. I would like to use matlab, with the slight different being that I want the spheres to have a particular image on them.

Is this possible and if so what would be a good starting point?

Comment: Just from the top of my head: use some 3D-plotting function to plot your celled cube and plot a sphere on each cell centre with half the cell width as radius, using`scatter3`. How you are supposed to get images on the spheres I have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it using [bubbleplot3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8231-bubbleplot3) from the File Exchange to plot an array of evenly spaced spheres, in addition to using [warp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/warp.html) to display an image as a texture-mapped surface for your spheres. Basically create the spheres with `bubbleplot3` and then fetch each individual surface object in a for loop and call `warp` on them to replace their texture map with an image.

For generating the gridded cube I have no credit whatsoever and slightly modified @Raf's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309188/how-to-plot-3d-grid-cube-in-matlab).

```
clc;clear;close all

%// Read image
C = flipud(imread('peppers.png'));

%// Generate array of spheres
Radius = 1;
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(0:2:4,0:2:4,0:2:4);
r=repmat(Radius,1,numel(x));

%// Call bubbleplot3
hBubble = bubbleplot3(x,y,z,r,[],[],[],[]);

hold on

%// Get surfaces objects
SurfHandles = findobj('type','surface');

%// Use warp function to replace colordata with image
for k = 1:numel(SurfHandles)
    warp(SurfHandles(k).XData,SurfHandles(k).YData,SurfHandles(k).ZData,C)
end

%// Now cube.
%// Credit to Raf here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309188/how-to-plot-3d-grid-cube-in-matlab
CubeData = -1:2:5;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(CubeData,CubeData);                         
x = [X(:) X(:)]';                                
y = [Y(:) Y(:)]';
z = [repmat(CubeData(1),1,length(x)); repmat(CubeData(end),1,length(x))];
col = 'b';

plot3(x,y,z,col,'Color','k');                                         
plot3(y,z,x,col,'Color','k');
plot3(z,x,y,col,'Color','k');

rotate3d on
```

And output:

[image]

Comment: haha thanks @rayryeng that was fun! It looks even better with the cube! :)

Comment: This is amazing, my best dissertation diagram!

Comment: great! If it helped could you mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the tick mark beside it? That means you don't need anymore help. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the wrapping http://imgur.com/32JHILr. It looks like the images are not exactly mapping to the sphere and the geometry is overlapping it.

Comment: mhh maybe the image is a bit too small to be correctly rendered? What if you use `imresize` to increase its size?

Comment: The image is huge actually, attempted to scale it down and it is still occurring.

Comment: Ok I'll try to check this out when I have some time that's interesting!